# Python 3 Fibonacci Sequence (lists)

Tags: list, python-3.x, numbers, pycharm, fibonacci

I'm trying to make a program in python that adds the fibonacci number in a list and then prints out the list, I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it keeps giving this error IndexError: list index out of range

`

```
size = 8
ls = [0, 1]
counter = 2

while size > 0:
    ls[counter].append(ls[counter - 1] + ls[counter - 2])
    size -= 1
    counter += 1
print(ls)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It's just that you cannot append to `ls[counter]` but to `ls`

```
size = 8
ls = [0, 1]
counter = 2
while size > 0:
    ls.append(ls[counter - 1] + ls[counter - 2])
    size -= 1
    counter += 1

print (ls)
```